# is there a html5shiv for IE9?

Tags: html

Im using a jQuery horizontal Accordion plugin which relies heavily on HTML5 &  CSS3 - in Firefox and Chrome (latest) it works as advertised however, suprisingly IE9 does not begin to render it correctly, a problem i expected with ie versions 8 and below. The code includes an 'if' condition to check for pre version 9 to load a html5 shiv but it still renders IE9 badly (see images). Is there a pollyfill or shiv?? I despise IE with a vengeance, always have, and today i think ill cease developing for it altogether.

[image: screenshot of rendering in IE9]
[image: screenshot of rendering in Firefox (Latest)]

Comment: IE9 was still not very standards compliant, unlike IE10 (mostly compliant) and IE11 (almost entirely compliant). Personally I have experienced quirks in IE9 only that are not present in IE8! IIRC, the HTML5 shiv script is supposed to do individual feature detection and load whatever the browser in question doesn't support, so you can probably just have it run in all browsers regardless of vendor or version. Plus, doing browser version detection kind of defeats the shiv's purpose of feature detection.

Comment: Hmmm, Yes ive read alot about IE 10 and 11 and its beggers belief that its taken 11 versions for them to comply with W3C. I can afford to make a the decision to not develop for IE but i understand other devs have no choice. I will however begin a campaign to get aal devs who work commercially to try to persuade there audience to move to a better browser which is a feat and a half in itself.

Comment: As a web developer myself, I wouldn't mind developing for IE11. IMHO, if you want to start a campaign, do it to get people off of IE8/9.

Comment: Yes but that means an MS OS upgrade (see what MS did there?) blink and you'll miss it!